# XCode 4 Snapshots file set management

Tags: xcode4

I've been using snapshots in Xcode 4 and have restored some old files now and then or compared the current version of a file with a previous version occasionally, so I thought it was pretty handy.
But then, I've tried using it on a fairly big project with dozens of files and I have just realized that this sucker doesn't remember the actual list of files that are part of the project in the snapshot, or at least it doesn't make uses of it.

For instance, at a certain time, I make a snapshot (S1) of my project, which contains files A, B, and C. Then later, I rework my code, delete file B and introduce files D and E, and make a number of snapshots (S2, S3, S4).
Now suppose I recover S3 in full. Well, I end up with file B in my project folder, even though it's not part of the project since snapshot S2...

There's a way to select which files you want to restore out of the complete set, but when I have 100+ files in the project, I don't even remember which ones are really still used and which ones are old and I can't be bothered clicking those stupid checkmarks one after the other to remove those files I don't want.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is there a way to tell Xcode to restore only those files that were indeed in the project at the time of the snapshot (as it should do if it had any sort of brain)?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use `git`?  Wouldn't that do what you want?

Comment: Well I guess that's what I'm going to use indeed. Is there way to commit all changes and then tag all files with the same tag so that they can all be restored later as a whole? That's what I was hoping snapshots would bring me.

Comment: Once you create a tag you basically create a snapshot (it's like a named commit) and when you checkout that tag all the files will be in the state they were then you tagged the repo.

Comment: I was hoping for a simple way to do this directly from within Xcode but I guess not, I'll have to do the tagging from the command line or some other GUI. Oh well. Thanks though.

Comment: I use SourceTree (http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) sometimes in preference to the Xcode source code elements (especially as Xcode 4.3.2 crashes during remote pushes for me).  It's full featured, quick and free.

Comment: I installed SourceTree and it works nicely, tagging is a snap. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I'd like an answer to the original question: how to prevent a snapshot from including files that were deleted prior to making the snapshot?  Perhaps this is a bug.

Comment: I can even delete the references and the files (move them to Trash), use a Finder search to locate all other files of that name, delete those, and then Empty Trash -- now, the files are not on my system anymore -- then quit and relaunch my project, and finally make a new snapshot. That snapshot contains the deleted files! A Restore brings them back from the dead! The restored files are not shown in the project's file list, but they've been added back in the location where they used to be. Can somebody else confirm this for me?

Comment: I think snapshots are stored in disk images, so the finder won't be able to find them. Deleting all those files manually won't remove them from the snapshot (which makes sense, a snapshot is kind of a backup). Anyway, restoring a snapshot indeed restores all files, not just those that were present at the time of the snapshot. This was what my gripe was all about. Bottom line: snapshots are pretty much useless, I stopped using them.